# Is $f$ will be onto if $X$ is not compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> let $( X,d)$  be  a  compact metric space  . let $f : X \rightarrow X$  be  such that  $d(f(x) , f(y) ) = d(x,y)$  for all  $x , y   \in   X$  then $f$ is  onto
>
> Now  my  question is that Is  the result still true  if $X$ is  not compact  ?

My attempt  : I think  yes  take  $X = \mathbb{R}$  and $f(x) = x$

Comment: That is not really an attempt to be honest. Cases work for counter examples, but if you think it's true you need to prove it in generality.

Comment: okss  i will  try @Fimpellizieri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Can you think of a counter-example with $X=\Bbb N$?

Comment: if $f : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ and $f(n) = n$  then $ f$ will be onto   ...is its true ?

Comment: Try to make it not onto, don't just pick the first example you think of. @jasmine

Comment: I've changed it to 'Can you think of a *counter*-example?'

Comment: @TrevorGunn u mean  constant function $ f(n) =1$ ?

Comment: The constant function is not an isometry, ie, it does not satisfy the distance condition.

Comment: okss  got its@Fimpellizieri  $f(n) = n +1$  that mean  $d(f(x) , f(y) ) =  n+1 - m-1 = n-m$ (isometry). Is its true ?

Comment: It is true that $f(n) = n+1$ is an isometry. Is it true that $f$ is onto?